# 1060 - Duplicate column name 'XX'

Tags: php, sql, syntax, comments

I am getting the weirest error ever and there should be no reason at all I should be getting this as I have completed removed the column from the statement and it still saying it's duplicated??

Here's my query

Original (should still work)

```
$select_post_comments = $db->query("SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM spud_groups_posts LEFT JOIN spud_groups_comments ON spud_groups_posts.post_id = spud_groups_comments.post_id 
                WHERE spud_groups_posts.post_id='$post_id_feed' ORDER BY spud_groups_comments.comment_id
) a ORDER BY comment_id");
```

New (still not working?!)

```
$select_post_comments = $db->query("SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM spud_groups_posts LEFT JOIN spud_groups_comments ON spud_groups_posts.time_posted = spud_groups_comments.comment_id 
                WHERE spud_groups_posts.post_body='$post_id_feed' ORDER BY spud_groups_comments.comment_id
) a ORDER BY comment_id");
```

What's the problem here and why is it asking for a query that's not even being specified in the new one, all I want to do is order the comments a certain way

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to add a more precise description of the issue and a table structure example.

Comment: there's not much more to say I am getting this error 
Duplicate column name 'post_id' and I am not sure why I am even getting this query
look at the query and please let me know if im doing anything wrong

Answer (score 2):

`post_id` column exits in both the tables `spud_groups_posts` and `spud_groups_comments`

you are doing `select *` in the sub query that is causing duplicate column error

you can refer column name with table prefix and select only needed columns.

```
SELECT spud_groups_posts.post_id as groups_post_id, .. FROM spud_groups_posts LEFT JOIN ..
```